# MySQL Error - ALTER is not valid at this position

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I am trying to execute the following query into **MySQL Workbench 8.0.15**:

```
ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'password';
```

I am receiving an error that states:

> "ALTER" is not valid at this position for this server version, expecting : CACHE, CHECKSUM, COMMIT, DEALLOCATE, DO, EXECUTE, ...

What could I do to fix this error?

Comment: The problem is with what you wrote before it. It thinks this is a continuation of that query.

Comment: Show more context where this statement appears. Maybe you're missing a `;` on the previous line.

Comment: This query is actually the only query I'm trying to execute in MySQL Workbench.

Comment: Which server version is that?

Comment: So because I'm a MySQL Workbench newbie, I realized I had not setup a localhost connection with a 'root' username. After I had done this, I no longer received the error. I really have to follow more tutorials. Thanks all for any info provided!

Comment: Having the same issue when trying to simply query `CREATE ROLE someRole;`. Getting the error "'CREATE' is not valid at this position for this server version, expecting : CACHE, CHECKSUM, COMMIT, DEALLOCATE, DO, EXECUTE, ..."

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, I fix this error by creating a new connection in Mysql Workbench